# HttpClient reading entire file before upload. UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, httpclient, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

I'm making an UWP app that uploads files to facebook, I'm using a custom HttpContent to upload the files in 4k blocks to minimize the memory usage for big files (>100mb) and to report progress.

My custom HttpContent UploadWithProgressHttpContent:

```
 class UploadWithProgressHttpContent : HttpContent
{
    private readonly IProgress<OperationProgress> _progress;
    private readonly OperationProgress _data;
    private readonly Stream _file;
    private readonly int _bufferSize;
    private readonly CancellationToken _token;

    public UploadWithProgressHttpContent(
        IProgress<OperationProgress> progress,
    OperationProgress data,
    Stream file,
    int bufferSize,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    _progress = progress;
    _data = data;
    _file = file;
    _bufferSize = bufferSize;
    _token = token;
}



protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
{
    return CopyStreamWithProgress(_file, stream, _progress, _token, _data, _bufferSize);
}

public static async Task<Stream> CopyStreamWithProgress(
    Stream source,
    Stream destination,
    IProgress<OperationProgress> progress,
    CancellationToken token,
    OperationProgress progressData,
    int bufferSize
    )
{
    int read, offset = 0;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    using (source)
    {
        do
        {
            read = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize, token);

            await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read, token);

            offset += read;
            progressData.CurrentSize = offset;
            progress.Report(progressData);
        } while (read != 0);
    }

    return destination;
}
}
```

What I'm experiencing (using fiddler) is that the whole file gets putted in memory before the upload starts (my progress meter reaches 100% before the upload even starts).

I did try setting the `TransferEncodingChunked` to `true`, and setting the file content length but the issue remains.

The upload source is inside a PCL (if it matters). I'm using the latest version of `System.Net.Http`. If need I'm using this the exact same way as it is used in the [MediaFire SDK](https://github.com/MediaFire/mediafire-csharp-open-sdk/blob/master/Source/MediaFireSDK/Http/HttpClientAgent.cs)

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Added the HttpClient usage:

```
public async Task<T> Upload<T>(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();


    var cli = new HttpClient(handler);

    foreach (var header in Headers)
    {
        cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }

    var parameters = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    foreach (var parameter in Parameters)
    {
        parameters.Add(new StringContent(parameter.Value), parameter.Key);
    }

    if (fileStream != null)
    {
        var fileContent = new UploadWithProgressHttpContent(ProgressOperation, ProgressData, fileStream,
            _chunkBufferSize, Token, fileStream.Length);

        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeTypeHelper.GetMimeType(fileName));
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(StreamParamName);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
        fileContent.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
        parameters.Add(fileContent, StreamParamName);
    }

    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(method, Path) { Content = parameters };
    if (fileStream != null)
        req.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;


    var completionOption = HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead;


    var resp = await cli.SendAsync(req, completionOption, Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return await DeserializeObject<T>(resp);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't fix this issue with a custom HttpContent, my alternative was using a StreamContent, and making a Stream Decorator that reported progressed on read. By using a StreamContent HttpClient streams the content without bringing it (all) to memory.

Comment: Not exactly, I'm using a custom httpcontent, I already check that using a stream content it works as expected, I just want to know why it doesn't work with a custom httpcontent, or if there is any way it would.

Comment: Can you share also the piece code around HttpClient ? Btw. I would consider using wire shark instead (not sure if adding fiddler as http proxy isn't messing with the traffic).

Comment: Done, thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try with an override for HttpContent.TryComputeLength?

Comment: Side note, might want to change your `HttpClient` to a single instance to be used by this call.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client)

Comment: I'm aware that HttpClient should have instances pooled, but since I'm on a multi-thread environment I didn't want to deal with synchronization while I build the app. @Uwe I did try that without success.

Answer (score 2):

You have the same problem as quantum mechanics - the act of observing changes the observed. Fiddler does not support request streaming - see
[Fiddler makes HttpWebRequest/HttpClient behaviour unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824717/fiddler-makes-httpwebrequest-httpclient-behaviour-unexpected)
and
http://www.telerik.com/forums/is-it-possible-to-not-buffer-requests

Using wireshark I can see the chunks.

Comment: Not quite, If I disable fiddler the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

After hours wasted on this issue, it seams that this a HttpClient implementation issue. 
So if you want stream content to a server (and report progress) the best alternative is to use a `StreamContent` and decorate the reads to report the progress.

NOTE: This is true to the 4.3.1 version of `System.Net.Http` and version 2.2.29 `Microsoft.Net.Http` nugget packages